# Lock/unlock std::unique_lock in different functions

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency

I'm writing a program that uses a condition variable as such:

```
bool flag;
std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cond;

{
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
  cond.wait(lock, [&]{ return flag; });

  // ... do some stuff
  // ... do some more stuff

  flag = false;

} // lock unlocked here
```

Now I'm faced with the problem that "do some stuff" and "do some more stuff" are actually implemented in two separate callback functions invoked one after the other from somewhere else, i.e.:

```
void callback1() {
   std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
   cond.wait(lock, [&]{ return flag; });

   // ... do some stuff
} // ERROR! lock unlocked too early

void callback2() {
   // ... do some more stuff
  flag = false;
} // lock should be unlocked here
```

How can I solve this issue? I could encapsulate both callbacks in some object that holds the lock as a member variable but that seems to me like it goes against the intended semantics of `std::unique_lock`.

EDIT: more context:

Someone else has written a class `Foo` that looks as follows:

```
class Foo
{
public:
  void bar() {
    before_bar_callback();

    // ...
    
    after_bar_callback();
  }

private:
  virtual void before_bar_callback() {}
  virtual void after_bar_callback() {}
};
```

I can't modify `Foo::bar` and it runs in a separate thread. I would like to wait on a condition variable in `before_bar_callback` and then set `flag = false` and unlock the associated lock in `after_bar_callback`.

Comment: This is not enough information to come up with a balanced answer. Why 2 callbacks instead of one. If they're so dependent they should I think be combined into one.

Comment: @PKramer I have added more context.

Comment: I think I see where you are going with this. If I'm understanding correct, you want both of the callbacks to be basically atomic because you don't want to risk "invalidation" between the two. I worked on a project that dealt with this, and they ultimately decided that unlocking between the callbacks was okay. Otherwise you end up in all kinds of strange deadlock scenarios. The reality was that the program wasn't really multithreaded enough to cause errors (but it did happen). After this, I believe the only solution is to have async eventing, which comes with its own challenges.

Comment: With that split interface, you cannot use RAII :/

Comment: You can use `std::condition_variable_any` and pass `mtx` directly to its `wait`. This way you won't automatically unlock when `callback1` returns.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thanks! I didn't know about `std::condition_variable_any`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your information this is the closest I could get to a kind of RAII approach.
When a class doesn't do what you want, sometimes wrapping it helps.
And this is what I could come up with. Ideally you still should check if Foo can't still be modified by the "owner".

The idea : acquire a lock before Foo gets a chance to do its job and call your callbacks. That way you know the lock is active inside your callbacks.

```
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// your stand in for Foo,
// the class you cannot change

class  Foo 
{
public:
    Foo() = default;
    virtual ~Foo() = default;

    void bar()
    {
        // todo construct a context here
        before_callback();
        // work here
        after_callback();
        // and destroy it here.
    }

private:
    virtual void before_callback() {};
    virtual void after_callback() {};

};

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------
// A class that should look like Foo but wraps it
// Foo is a member and FooWrapper can intercept calls
// to Foo and do extra things.

class MyFoo :
    protected Foo
{
public:
    MyFoo() = default;
    virtual ~MyFoo() = default;

    // shadows base classes bar intentionally
    void bar() 
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock{ m_mtx };
        m_lock = &lock;
        Foo::bar();
    };

    void before_callback() override
    {
        //lock is active
        m_cv.wait(*m_lock, [this] {return m_flag; });
        std::cout << "before_callback" << std::endl;
    }

    void after_callback() override
    {
        //lock is active
        std::cout << "after_callback" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    bool m_flag{ true };
    std::condition_variable m_cv;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex>* m_lock{ nullptr };
    std::mutex m_mtx;
};

int main()
{
    MyFoo foo;
    foo.bar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As I read, `Foo` is an "interface", so wrapping it is not possible. And you have then to use inheritance normally. (and if you wrap it `before_callback`/`after_callback` is mostly irrelevant anyway as lock might be obtained before calling `m_foo.bar()`).

Comment: @Jarod42 Interface can be wrapper, and I agree the callbacks don't have to be in the wrapper as long as they can access the (pointer) to the lock. I don't really like relying on workarounds (including this one) anyway. I've learned over the years that it is better to solve the real issue (design) even if that means going to the suppliers of the code I use.

Comment: I meant that, as the code is shown, I understand that it should have somewhere a `lib_function(Foo&);` that you cannot change (as `Foo`).

Comment: I see now that OP hints at having to overriding before_callback/after_callback (even though he made the virtual functions private). Then a virtually derived class can overrride the methods and still provide a new bar implmentation that locks and forwards to Foo::bar(). But yes if it is a lib_function(Foo&) things don't look so good

Comment: @PKramer Yeah overriding is the idea (and still works with private member functions).

Comment: Example updated.

Comment: This seems like it would work. But is this better than just using `std::conditional_variable_any` as suggested in a comment above?

Comment: I don't know which is better since I don't know std::conditional_variable_any. I do have tons of experience with std::mutex/std::unique_lock. And I know this example will not only protect your condition variable but also the rest the data used in the handler. And that this solution is exception safe, so if either handler throws the lock is freed. At the very least you gave me an interesting puzzle :)